# LWJGL cannot properly draw texture

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

When I'm trying to draw a texture(which contains only a red color) on a quad I get something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXw4.png)
It doesn't cover all quad, only a part of it. I've tried different sizes(of course, their widths and heights were an even numbers), formats of pictures, tried to make it using Paint and Photoshop, but always get the same result.

Here is my code:

```
package test2;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_MODELVIEW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor3f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glOrtho;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glTexCoord2f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex2i;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      try {
        Display.setFullscreen(true);
        Display.setTitle("test");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        while(true){
            glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            Texture t = null;

            try {
                t = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("texture.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            t.bind();

            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
              glVertex2i(100, 100);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
              glVertex2i(100, 200);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
              glVertex2i(200, 200);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
              glVertex2i(200, 100);
            glEnd();


            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the image I would guess, that the rectangle only covers parts of the screen and that the texture is applied on the full rectangle. (since you draw the quad always 100px in size)

Comment: What's the size of the texture? I believe Slick pads textures to power of 2 sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Now I found, that the textures, which weight and height presents (2^n) number is drawing perfectly. But what me to do with other textures? Is it possible to use them in OpenGL properly?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, it's Slick that pads the textures to powers of two. Use something else to load the textures.